# Transactional Email Styling not displaying on preview

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I'm trying to style the content of the email example is the `New Ordern` or the `Order Confirmation` Template. Now I selected this template and added some css styling on this field under the `Template Style` field. But upon saving and when I clicked the preview button the style that I made does not take effect or not being displayed (Note: I'm using an ID and I'm sure the ID selector is correct). Now since It didn't work and I thought it's just a cache issue I placed the styling within the element itself. Upon viewing the style show up.

Is there a reason why my styling does not show up when I place it in the `Template Style`?

Below is the screenshot of the NEW ACCOUNT template I made

[image]

Now below is when I click the preview of the template

[image]

I don't really understand why I can't view the changes? I also added the styling in the `app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<MODULE>/web/css/email-inline.less` but upon clicking preview I don't see the changes. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: That works in default installation. You can use your browser's element Inspector tool to see if the class is redefined somewhere else.

Comment: @subroutines already did and I can't see the styling I just added and also the classes is unique and no one is using the same ID